# How to Remove Empty Strings

Tags: sql, string, hadoop, trim

I'm trying to find a way to trim or remove spaces in what appeared to be empty strings so that when I look for a min value I get a result with characters and not an empty string with spaces.

Originally I tried excluding empty fields ( !="" ) however since the empty strings contain spaces its technically not an empty string so I tried Trimming and still cant get the result set that I need.

```
select trim(Field_1) as Field_1
from Table_1
where Field_Date between '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-31'
and Field_1 != ""
order by Field_1 asc
```

The Result Set that I get is:

- Blank (6 Spaces)
- Blank (6 Spaces)
- Blank (6 Spaces)
- ABC
- DEF
- GHI

The Result Set that I Need

- ABC
- DEF
- GHI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `WHERE` condition is not being trimmed whereas your `SELECT` is.

In your case you are using Field_1 as the reference in your condition, which appears to refer to the table's column and not the alias you created by saying `trim(Field_1) as Field_1`

If you only want results that have no whitespace there is no need to `trim()` your selected column since your condition enforces that your result can have no whitespace, so why not use `trim()` in your second condition?

That way every record's value for Field_1 will be trimmed *first* and then compared to "".

How about something like this?

```
select Field_1
from Table_1
where Field_Date between '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-31'
and trim(Field_1) != ""
order by Field_1 asc
```

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you so much for the solution as well as the explanation.

Comment: @ace123 Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd be looking at why you're getting empty strings in the first place.
If they're supposed to be empty record sets then you've certainly got some code inserting unnecessary spaces somewhere.

Fixing this issue would stop any blank statements from appearing in the SQL search as they would come back as null. This would also save you in future as blank spaces in a database can be quite a pain!

However, if you're still looking for a way to replace the spaces in your code I'd suggest reading this article:
[REPLACE Multiple Spaces with one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one)

I believe this will put you on the right track.

Comment: Good Point. Thank you for that

Comment: No problem, I've edited the answer to provide a link to replace spaces which I believe may help you for your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Field_1
from Table_1
where Field_Date between '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-31'
and Field_1 not like '% %'
order by Field_1 asc
```